# SQL Server copy rows to second table

Tags: sql-server, foreach

I have a table for bookings (table_b) that has around 1.3M rows. A second table (table_s) is used to note when these rows are needed to be accessed by a separate application.

Currently there are triggers to make a record in table_s but this doesn't help with all existing data.

I believe I need to have a query that selects the rows that exists in table_b but not table_s and then insert a row for each line.

Here is my current syntax but don't think it has been formed correctly

```
DECLARE @b_id  [INT] = 0;

WHILE(1 = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 10 
        @b_id = MIN([b].[b_id])
    FROM 
        [table_b] AS [b]
    LEFT JOIN 
        [table_s] AS [s] ON [b].[b_id] = [s].[b_id]
    WHERE 
        [s].[b_id] IS NULL;

    IF @b_id IS NULL 
        BREAK;

    INSERT INTO [table_s] ([b_id], [processed])
    VALUES (@b_id, 0);
END;
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a unique composite table just to get your data imported using a "select into" with appropriate conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically everything is fine. But there are some misconceptions present in your query

```
select top 10 @b_id = MIN(b.b_id)
```

a variable can hold just one value, even though you select `top 10` it will assign single value to variable. Your current approach will loop for each non existing record

I don't think for 1 million records insert we need to split the insert into batches. Try this way

```
INSERT INTO table_s
            (b_id,
             processed)
SELECT b_id,
       0
FROM   table_b AS b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table_s AS s
                   WHERE  b.b_id = s.b_id)
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for clearing up my errors. Top 'top 10' was only to make it manageable while I was getting the syntax correct